# laravel unable to fetch data using @yield() before setting it into @section()

Tags: laravel, yield

I'm trying to get some piece of information before setting it as shown below

```
<div id="collapseOne">Total sales amount is @yield('total_final')</div>

{{--*/ $total = 0 /*--}}
@foreach($sale_agent as $key => $sale)
{{--*/ $total = $total + $sale->amount /*--}}
@endforeach
@section('total_final', $total)
<div>Total sale: @yield('total_final')</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap accordion to display multiple seller sales, I want to display the total sales amount on the accordion header (i.e.: before entering the foreach loop), how every I'm also displaying the same value with in the accordion without any problem.

I'm just trying to avoid another foreach loop which is required just to calculate the total sales amount.

Please suggest me how to get this task done efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="collapseOne">Total sales amount is @yield('total_final')</div>

@section('total_final')
{{ $sale_agent->sum('amount') }}
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to calculate the total in your controller and pass it to the view.